# how to Get image from Facebook Page API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am fetching from Facebook API for Facebook Page but it returned me as Black diamond with question

```
$pictureObj = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$page_id/picture?type=large");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an Access Token:

```
$pictureObj = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . '/picture?type=large&access_token=xxxx');
```

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/